# Tell Batch 'find' string has to end with newline

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm currently trying to determine if a string is in a certain file using batch `find`. Therefore I'm using the following code:

```
>nul find "stringToSearch" file.txt && ( 
  REM String exists.
) || (
  REM String does not exist.
)
```

The structure of my `file.txt` can be seen as the following:

```
randomString
randomString2
stringToSearch
randomString3
stringToSearch_additional
```

The Problem here is that `find` will always return true when `stringToSearch_additional` is in there, even when just `stringToSearch` is not. So is there any way to search for `stringToSearch` only, ending the line right after the last letter? I also cannot check for a whole line because there might be some other words in front of every line (that I don't have control over).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findstr` with the `/e /b` switches or regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, works just as it should.